# OpenWRT display devices on network in commandline and store to file

Tags: networking, router, ip-address, openwrt

I would like to display the devices, their IP & mac address via SSH into my OpenWRT flashed router is there a native method or is a package required? if so, which would be least labor intensive?

I'd use 'sed' to store these details as a txt file and have the script for that written already. (the easy part)

Comment: [Display connected clients and processor load](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=4507)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arp -n >> file location/file

### or

arp -n > file location/file